# PHP Selenium Firefox browser Proxy socks5

Tags: php, selenium

How to setup proxy settings for Firefox browser, because I reader few resources and I'm still unable to setup that proxy, only HTTP, https, ftp proxy is working but I need socks5.
This is the info for PHP https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/wiki/HowTo-Work-with-proxy
this is the info about desiredCapabilities https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#proxy-json-object

when I initialize Firefox like this:

```
    $caps = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
    $caps->setCapability(WebDriverCapabilityType::PROXY,
                         [
                             'proxyType' => 'manual',
                             'httpProxy' => 'localhost:8000',
                             'sslProxy' => 'localhost:8000',
                             'socksProxy' => 'localhost:8000'
                         ]
    );
    $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $caps);
```

and I go to opened firefox browser window and go to network config page I see only httpProxy, sslProxy but not socksProxy. Do anyone have this issue resolved, NOTE I use docker and FF 80+ version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below config

```
$caps->setCapability(WebDriverCapabilityType::PROXY,
                     [

                         'httpProxy' => 'localhost:8000',
                         'sslProxy' => 'localhost:8000',
                         "proxyType"=> "MANUAL",
                         "socksProxy"=>'localhost:8000',
                         "socksVersion"=>5
                     ]
```

Comment: it almost worked, but now I get an exception java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer, but good thing is that FF have proxy setup

Comment: ok, after rebuilding Dockerfile with FF 83 it worked